# Coupled differential equation with repeated roots.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Problem**

I have two differential equations

$ \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{dy}{dt} + x + y = 0$

$ 2 \frac{dx}{dt} +  \frac{dy}{dt} + x = 0 $

initial conditions: $y(0) = 1$ and $x(0) = 0$

**Attempt**

I've solved the system via the Matrix method of setting determinant to $0$, and I got $w = -1$ --> a repeated root.

I'm not sure why I have to use the extra $t$ factor

$x = (At + B) e^{-t}$

$y = (Ct + D) e^{-t} $

to solve these equations.

In addition when I tried using the extra factor, using the initial conditions, I just got $0 = A\cdot 0+ B$ and $1= C\cdot 0 + D$, which I can't use to find $C$ and $A$. I found $B$ and $D$ to be $0$ and $1$ respectively.

Comment: Is the second one written correctly?

Comment: @Moo I'm sorry, it's corrected in my edit.

Comment: I get that $x'=y$ by subtracting the equations, then using that to get $y'=-(x+2y)$.

Comment: As per jdod's observation, you have $y=x'$. This implies that the coefficients of $y$ are determined by those of $x$. (Also, should it have been $Ct+D$ in your expression for $y$?)

Comment: "I've solved the system via the Matrix method of setting determinant to 0, and..." You should show **much** more precisely what you did.

Comment: isn't that for all coupled differential equations? That x and y are related? using the matrix i found that setting w to -1, then matrix multiplying with (x,y) that -(At+B) = (Ct+D)

Comment: "using the matrix i found that setting w to -1, then matrix multiplying with (x,y) that -(At+B) = (Ct+D)" Yeah, you already wrote that and this was already impossible to decipher.

Comment: Can you check again that you have the equations written correctly and the initial conditions correct? I am typing a complete solution for you but find that your initial conditions are incompatible with the equations. I will check my work again though.

Comment: @jdods just checked again and they are correct. Wolfram gets the answer $x=te^{-t}$ and $y= -e^{-t} * (t-1)$

Comment: if anyone else wants me to show how  found $w=-1$ for my trial solution $x = Ae^{wt}, y = B e^{wt}$ ( I think these are OK to use as trial solutions?) from a matrix form of the system of equations, I'll edit it in but I'm not sure that will be useful for anyone trying to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the other solution, the matrix method is overkill, but since you're interested, here it is.

Your matrix system is $\mathbf{x}'=A\mathbf{x}$ where 
$$A=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & -2
\end{matrix}\right)$$

The eigenvalue is $-1$ with a multiplicity of $2$. The first eigenvector is $\xi=(-1,1)^T$ but we have to find a **generalized eigenvector** $\eta$ such that $(A-\lambda I)\eta=\xi$. We find that $\xi=(0,-1)^T$ works.

The solutions are 
$\mathbf{x}_1(t)=\mathbf{\xi}e^{-t}$ and $\mathbf{x}_1(t)=\mathbf{\xi}te^{-t}+\mathbf{\eta}e^{-t}$. This is a standard technique.

The solution with repeated roots is:

$$
\mathbf{x}(t)=
c_1\left(\begin{matrix}
-1  \\
1 
\end{matrix}\right)e^{-t}+
c_2\left(\begin{matrix}
-1  \\
1 
\end{matrix}\right)te^{-t}+
c_2\left(\begin{matrix}
0  \\
-1 
\end{matrix}\right)e^{-t}
$$

Using your initial conditions give $c_2=-1$ and $c_1=0$.

**Regarding the extra $t$:**
First, the extra $t$ is required because of the repeated root. In order to capture the entire set of possible solutions (to the matrix equation), we need two linearly independent solutions: $x=x_0e^{-t}$ and $y=y_0e^{-t}$ won't work since they are essentially the same (save for different initial values).

Here is how I prefer to understand it. Two homogeneous first order equations can always be turned into a single homogeneous second order equation:

$$\mathbf{x}'=A\mathbf{x}$$ with $\mathbf{x}=(x,y)^T$ becomes $$x''-\text{tr}(A)x'+\text{det}(A)x=0$$

where tr$(A)$ is the trace of  matrix $A$ and det$(A)$ is the determinant.

The second order equation gives a characteristic equation: $r^2-\text{tr}(A)r+\text{det}(A)=0$ which gives roots $r_1$ and $r_2$. These give two solutions $x_i=e^{r_it}$ for $i=1,2$. Since the equation is second order, we *need* two linearly independent solutions (there is theory to back this up). We construct the general solution: $x=c_1x_1+c_2x_2$ then solve for the $c_i$ coefficients using initial conditions.

However, when $r_1=r_2=r$, it just so happens that $x_1=e^{rt}$ and $x_2=te^{rt}$ work. In higher order equations, you simply multiply by powers of $t$ enough times to make sure you get the required number of solutions corresponding to the multiplicity of the root (if $r=1$ has multiplicity $3$, then $x_k=t^{k-1}e^t$ are solutions for $k=1,2,3$).

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit confused however - my matrix was $$A=\left(\begin{matrix}
w+1 & w+1 \\
2w+1 & w
\end{matrix}\right)$$

Which I then took the determinant of, set to 0 and found w. I don't think I've really seen your method in my linear algebra course. One of the reasons I'm interested in the matrix method, by the way, is because I use it for more complicated systems too, of coupled pendula and such, so I wanted to make sure my technique is correct.

Comment: Since we can derive $x'=y$ and $y'=-x-2y$ from your equations it gives the linear system I gave where $\mathbf{x}=(x,y)^T$ and $\mathbf{x}'=A\mathbf{x}$. The technique I used is a standard technique for  $2\times2$ linear systems of first order differential equations.

Comment: @inya, I've added some details to the answer regarding the extra $t$. I hope it is helpful.

Comment: I've finally understood the matrix method you're describing (which is standard for coupled des, it appears) and your answer now makes sense.  how retakes can be useful, eh...

Answer (score 3):

In a so simple case, the method with matrix appears a bit overmuch.
$$\begin{cases}
x'+y'+x+y=0 \\
2x'+y'+x=0
\end{cases} \quad\to\quad (2x'+y'+x)-(x'+y'+x+y)=0 \quad\to\quad y=x'$$
$2x'+y'+x=2x'+x''+x=0\quad\to\quad x=Ae^{-t}+Bte^{-t}\quad\to\quad y=(-A+B)e^{-t}-Bte^{-t}$

Conditions : $\begin{cases}
x(0)=A=0 \\
y(0)=-A+B=1\quad\to\quad B=1
\end{cases} \quad\to\quad \begin{cases}
x=te^{-t} \\
y=(1-t)e^{-t}
\end{cases}$